# could not convert string to float: 'Jerry'

Tags: python, classification

I'm trying to build a decision tree regressor model and already split the training and testing dataset. However, once I tried to fit the decisiontreeclassifier into X_train and y_train, I am receiving the following error:

" could not convert string to float: 'Jerry' "

I even tried to convert the X_train data into array using numpy, created a column for the index as well but still facing the same issue. Kindly assist. Thanks

Comment: what are your X_train and y_train? can you give a few examples (for example, the first few rows) of your data? It seems like maybe your data are string, and obviously, a decision tree can only train with numerical data

Comment: Yes, those are strings and dtype of X_train is a mix of int64 & object whereas y_train is int64 only. I'm new to ML world and is a learning curve for me. Thanks!

Comment: @seermer decision trees can indeed be trained with categorical data. The limitation about using numerical data is because of how they're implemented in scikit. Hopefully this will be fixed in the future.

Comment: then you should first transform strings into numerical representations, there are many ways to do it (this is actually a whole research area by itself). a simple solution (but might not work well) would be to one-hot encode them

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly categorical data are still represented as numerical data to train in a decision tree, usually, in one-hot, I don't think it is possible to use the original categorical data directly (with strings, booleans, abstract categories etc.)

Comment: I wouldn't know how to implement trees myself, from scratch. But I'm sure that, at least in theory, it's possible to ask questions in a node of the kind "is name == 'Jerry'?", the same way you could do it with "is name ==  4?" or is "is name >  4?"

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html), decision trees are:

> Able to handle both numerical and categorical data. However, the scikit-learn implementation does not support categorical variables for now.

Scikit learn's trees need to use numbers to represent categories. This is a limitation of [how it's implemented in sklearn](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/238532/309334), not a limitation of trees themselves.

You can use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to convert categorical features into numerical ones, but...

If there's the possibility that some values for the categories are not represented in the test set, [one-hot-encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) is a better option.

Another (important) advantage of OHE is that it doesn't impose order in the feature. i.e. you don't get the awkward scenario where Jerry > Joe > Ben. **This artificial order can be learned by your model**.

Note that both `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder` are a transformers. So they have `fit()`, `fit_transform()` and `transform()` methods. As with most trasnformers, the typical workflow would be to *fit_transform* the training and then just *transform* the test.